# How efficient is the MongoDB $in operator?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query

Let's say I will have millions of comments that are cross-posted to multiple points of interest. Should I store each cross-posted comment multiple time:

```
{
  user_id: 1, 
  text: "hello world",
  poi_id: some_id1
}
{
  user_id: 1, 
  text: "hello world",
  poi_id: some_id2
}
```

or should I do it as an array

```
{
  user_id: 1, 
  text: "hello world",
  poi_ids: [some_id1, some_id2]
}
```

The first can just use an index on poi_id and query with blazing speed, but stores a redundant copy of the comment. The second one makes more intuitive sense as a database structure, and saves space, but I'm worried about query efficiency of using $in if I want to, say, get all the comments associated with some_id1.

Comment: i think efficient enough, as long as mongodb faster than sql

Comment: But really I think you are misunderstanding what `$in` is actually for. To simply look up "some_id1" as a singular value you just ask for that value on the field that happens to contain an array. You don't need special operators just for array values since MongoDB does not care. Your thinking seems to be in reverse and I [posted about this some time ago](https://snakierten96.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/to-nin-or-not-to-nin/).

Comment: Oh! Right, I read the definition of $in wrong.

Comment: So querying for {poi_ids: some_id1} would work as expected? If I ask MongoDB to ensureIndex on poi_ids, will it hash and index each element in the case where poi_ids is an array?

Comment: @wuxiekeji Well yes it does. This ultimately comes down to "how many duplicates" in your terminology are expected by your application. This really has nothing to do with `$in` or "performance" as your question is asking. The only real consideration is a "large number" of array items ( 500 or more as a guide) are not a good idea in both terms of storage allocation and also query performance. So the actual question you are asking is not really valid to the results you want to achieve.